# How to copy a folder with its content in ruby

Tags: ruby

I trying to copy a folder in ruby but receiving the error that "cannot copy directory to itself"

I dont understand why this happens, can someone please explain?  And how can I achieve it to copy a complete folder with new name. Here is my code where i try to copy the source folder with a timestamp in its name.

```
$releaseFolder = 'D:\ruby_workspace\fpsupdater\release'
$frontendSubPath = '\server\pdixfrontend\tomcat\conf'
$backendSubPath = '\server\pdixbackend\tomcat\conf\Catalina'


def println(text)
  puts $timestamp.inspect + ': ' + text
end


def getFileTimestamp()
 stamp = $timestamp.inspect
 stamp.gsub!(/\s+|:|\++/,"_")
end

def backupContext()

target = @configHash["target"]

if (Dir.exists?(target))

  println("backup of target " + target)
  println("need to backup: " + target + $frontendSubPath)
  println("need to backup: " + target + $backendSubPath)
  source = "#{target}#{$frontendSubPath}"
  backup = "#{target}#{$frontendSubPath}\\" + getFileTimestamp + "_conf" 
  println(source)
  println(backup)

  FileUtils.cp_r source , backup

else
  puts "cannot backup because target does not exists"
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot copy directory to the same directory, example:

```
FileUtils.cp_r "C:/TEST", "C:/TEST"
```

You cannot even make a recursive copy to the directory you are copying into, because then you can end up in a never ending loop!

```
FileUtils.cp_r "C:/TEST", "C:/TEST/SUBFOLDER"
```

If you need to do that, use a temporary directory and then move it back. Also optimize your code, getFileTimestamp can be much better :-)

Comment: Thank you, i copied it now to a tmp folder and move it back. this works. What do you suggest for the timestamp, I am new to ruby and open for recommendations :-)

Comment: Well if the timestamp is an object, try to call a method that will return it in the form you need. You can always convert into a time format and then reformat it. GOod luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
backup = "#{target}#{$frontendSubPath}\\" + getFileTimestamp + "_conf"
```

notice you r still using the frontedSubPath instead of the backendSubPath

Comment: thats correct, I want to copy the folder directly in the same folder as it is but with a new folder name